# Array.copy from C# to Delphi

Tags: c#, arrays, delphi

I have the next code in  C#. I need to convert it to Delphi but I am stuck in Array.copy from C#.

Maybe I'm tired and are not seeing the obvious.
My array copy function in delphi always return empty bytes.

Here is what I am trying:

```
C# code:
    byte[] buffer = new byte[200];
    byte[] tmpArray = new byte[16];
    int lenToCopy = 4;
    //fill buffer here
    buffer=ReadBuffer();
    Array.Copy(buffer, 2, tmpArray, 5, lenToCopy);
```

Delphi code:

```
var lenToCopy:integer;
    temparray, buffer:TBytes;
....
    begin
     lenToCopy := 4;
     setlength(tmpArray,16);
     fillchar(tmpArray[0],length(tmpArray),0);
     buffer:=GetBuffer();// buffer is ok here
     tmpArray:=ArrayCopy(buffer, 2, tmpArray, 5, lenToCopy); //here is the problem: I get an empty tmpArray result
    end;

    function ArrayCopy(src:TBytes;ixsource:integer;dest:TBytes;ixdest:integer;len:integer):TBytes;
    begin
      SetLength(result, len+ixdest);
      Move(src[ixsource],dest[ixdest],len);
      result:=dest;
    end;
```

Comment: SetLength(dest, len+ixdest);

Comment: Dalija Prasnikar. Thank you. It is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

What about this?

NewArray := Copy(OldArray, startIndex, Count);

If you need to copy into the middle of an array, you could also do this:

NewArray := Copy(TmpArray, 0, ixDest) + Copy(Buffer, 0, Len) + 
  Copy(TmpArray, ixDest + Len, MaxInt);

Of course that's not going to be super performant, but it will work.

I'm just shooting from the hip here... This also requires Delphi 10 Seattle at a minimum.